# Problem with datediff in sql

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos, phpmyadmin

In a database I want the following result:

List of requests that have taken more than 10 days to be resolved

My sql code is:

```
SELECT *,
DATEDIFF(fecha_de_fin, fecha_de_alta) AS dias_tiempo_respuesta
FROM peticiones
    WHERE 'dias_tiempo_respuesta'>=10
    ORDER BY dias_tiempo_respuesta ASC
;
```

When asking for the result I get the error 1292:

Warning: #1292 Wrong truncated DECIMAL value: 'days_time_response'

Comment: Estás en [es.so]. Las preguntas desben redactarse en castellano. Si quieres preguntar en inglés puedes ir a [so]. ¿Tan difícil es darse cuenta que la interfaz del sitio está en castellano?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use ...

SELECT *,
DATEDIFF(day, fecha_de_fin, fecha_de_alta) AS dias_tiempo_respuesta
FROM peticiones
WHERE DATEDIFF(day,fecha_de_fin, fecha_de_alta)>=10
ORDER BY DATEDIFF(day,fecha_de_fin, fecha_de_alta) ASC

or ...

Select *
from
(SELECT *,
DATEDIFF(day, fecha_de_fin, fecha_de_alta) AS dias_tiempo_respuesta
FROM peticiones) p
WHERE dias_tiempo_respuesta>=10
Order by dias_tiempo_respuesta

Comment: you are a genious!!

Thanks a lot. I copy the code that has worked. I had to modify the code that you shared with me a bit.

SELECT *,
    DATEDIFF(fecha_de_fin, fecha_de_alta) AS dias_tiempo_respuesta
    FROM peticiones
    WHERE DATEDIFF(fecha_de_fin, fecha_de_alta)>=10
    ORDER BY DATEDIFF(fecha_de_fin, fecha_de_alta) ASC
;

Comment: Estamos en [es.so]. Si quieren usar el idioma ingés, pueden ir a [so]. Este sitio se creó para preguntas y respuestas en castellano. ¿Tan difícil es darse cuenta de eso?. No respondas preguntas escritas en otro idioma y mucho menos respondas en otro idioma. Te invito a leer [answer] y a realizar el [tour]. Saludos